# Trying to find a sci fi novel; the title was translated to Russian as Cockroach Races

Tags: translation, story-identification

I'm trying to identify a novel (or short story) I read as a teen in the early 1990s. I don't remember the author but remember the title, *Cockroach Races*, as it was translated to Russian ("Tarakan'i Bega"), from which language I don't know, might have been original Russian. I tried searching for "Cockroach Races" in English-language literature but with no success.

The novel describes a technologically advanced society of the future where most people don't work but receive allowances, which they are required to spend to keep the economy going. A small subset of the population, "brainiacs" (distinguished by their prominent foreheads), work in research, but the majority of the population, alienated, bide their time in empty pursuits. A family is being described: the woman (wife? sister?) is having an affair with a brainiac hoping to conceive a "brainy" child, but the offspring turns out mentally deficient; the man (husband?) and his friends entertain themselves by racing cockroaches.

If the above sounds familiar, please let me know the author and title. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=de0qjGJPQqIC&pg=PT276&lpg=PT276&dq=Tarakan%27i+Bega+cockroach+races&source=bl&ots=cPmJo1IwAH&sig=GSm3phId7W3PbQwkIk10omFPNEs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH5ZXR3P3YAhXiQd8KHXZ-CcUQ6AEIQzAH#v=onepage&q=Tarakan'i%20Bega%20cockroach%20races&f=false ? Only reference I can find.

Comment: There's this Russian short story "Тараканьи бега": https://fantlab.ru/work221234